# Avoid multiple same url calls to the server when clicking on "forward" and "backward arrows" in .Net application

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am working on a .Net application(jQuery, Javascript on front end) where we can traverse through multiple pages. These pages have multiple buttons embedded and when clicking on these buttons we can traverse to the respective page based on the OnClick event.

Scenario 1: 
On clicking the button, there is only 1 server call being made to traverse to the next respective page.

Scenario 2: On clicking the forward button (or backward button) it makes several same Urls call to the server thus taking more time for the page load.

Here I compared the Url's in the Network tab on Inspecting the pages where we are facing issues. I am able to see the same url getting hit multiple times. I tried to find the first point in the code where exactly it is hitting but before hitting the code base itself all the same requests are getting queued up.

I need to correct the scenario 2 and I do not understand what is happening and having hard time understanding the behavior.

Comment: Anything you can demonstrate with code to better describe your problem is always appreciated.

Comment: This is one of the rarest of rare scenarios where we found it difficult to debug and know what part of the code is causing the issue. This is the reason I was not able to show any of the code here for this question.

Comment: After intensive debugging and spending 40 odd hours finally we are able to track the issue and apply workaround.                                                                 Cause: The number of POP events generated in a javascript file. Out of all 
             events the first event is a valid one and all other events are from VM's    Workaround: Consider the first event and neglect all the events generated from VM's.